# Spring Get Mapping isn't working

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, httprequest

I'm using Angular 4 with Spring backend. And.... My post request working fine. But the get request don't work. Look the code:

Frontend Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import { Aluno } from '../models/aluno.model';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

@Injectable()
export class UserDataService {

   private url = 'http://localhost:8080/getAluno';

   constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

   getAluno():Observable<Aluno>{
      return this.http.get<Aluno>(this.url);
   }
}
```

My spring backend provider:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.ifmg.tcc.TADs.Aluno;
import com.ifmg.tcc.TADs.LoginObject;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
public class LoginProvider {

  Gson gson = new Gson();

  private boolean verify(LoginObject lo){
    if(lo.getCode().equals("lucas") && lo.getPassword().equals("12345")){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
  }

  @PostMapping(value = "login")
  public ResponseEntity<?> verifyLogin(@RequestBody String login){
    System.out.println("LOGIN REALIZADO");
    LoginObject loginO = gson.fromJson(login, LoginObject.class);

    if(verify(loginO)){
        return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(true,HttpStatus.OK);
    }else{
        return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(false,HttpStatus.OK);
    }


  }

  @GetMapping(value = "/getAluno")
  public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<?> getAluno() {
    System.out.println("PEGANDO ALUNO");
    Aluno aluno = new Aluno("0001","Lucas Alves de Faria","2018/1","10/12/1995",true,"luke@email.com","(37) 999597899","127.831.956-58","MG-19.319.265");

    return new ResponseEntity<Aluno>(aluno, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
}
```

The function verify login in my backend working fine(I'm call this function in other service). But the fontend don't call the other function (getAluno)

Comment: Do you ever `.subscribe` to the request in your frontend? Are you saying the request never gets made, or gets made and fails?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you mean when you say "But the fontend don't call the other function (getAluno)". You may look at your network calls and verify the calls.

In your front component which calls your service, you need to have a subscribe, something like this :

```
this.yourService.getAluno().subscribe(
           (res: ResponseEntity) => {
                this.aluno = res.json;
            },
            (res: ResponseEntity) => this.onError(res.json)
);
```

Hope it helps you.